# How to show all articles in blog without tags etc

Tags: joomla-3.x, category-blog

I created my own design for **blog layout**, but after I understand, that blog don't display all articles - only **intro** of **lead**. Maybe I somehow can edit code and display **all articles**?

Sorry for my English...

Comment: I am afraid we don't have enough detail in this question.  Can you please help us to reproduce your problem by sharing what you did when you "created your own design for blog layout"?  Also, please take our [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Without any details of what or how you created your own Blog Layout it is impossible to say whether you have an issue your layout.

However you can check the Options tab for Articles in the administrator/back end and confirm that the '# Intro Articles' is set to more than 0. See image;

[image]

If I understand your question correctly I think you may have '# Leading Articles' set to One and '# Intro Articles' set to zero.

If that is not the case then we would need to see the code of the Blog Layout you have created.